# flowbite-react - customize slider problem

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

I want slider:

- hide arrow
- change color of dots
- change height, at the moment max size I can set `h-96`, in another way slider was hidden.

This is my code:

```
<div className="min-h-96">
          <Carousel
            slideInterval={5000}
            leftControl="&nbsp;"
            rightControl="&nbsp;"
          >
          ....
        </Carusel>
</div>
```

What I should change, and where I can find information about it?
On this page is readed, that I use new Carusel, but I don't understand it, anyone can help me?
https://flowbite.com/docs/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<div className="h-96">
      <Carousel
        slideInterval={5000}
        leftControl="&nbsp;"
        rightControl="&nbsp;"
      >
      ....
    </Carusel>
```

I had the same issue and this worked it